# $\mathbb{R}$ with the Right Half-open interval topology is Lindelof

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I want to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ with the topology generated by the intervals $[a,b)$ is Lindelof.

First, it is sufficient to show that every basic sets cover has a countable subcover.

Let $\{[a_{\alpha},b_{\alpha})\}_{\alpha\in J}$ be such cover. The sets $\{(a_{\alpha},b_{\alpha})\}_{\alpha\in J}$ cover $\mathbb{R}$ and are open in the standard topology, and since $\mathbb{R}$ is separable, it is Lindelof, hence there exists a countable subcover $\{(a_n,b_n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\mathbb{R}\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(a_n,b_n)$. But then,
$$
\mathbb{R}\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(a_n,b_n)\cup\{a_n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\} = \bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[a_n,b_n)
$$

Is this legit?

Comment: The sets $\{ (a_\alpha, b_\alpha) \}_{\alpha \in J}$ aren't necessarily a cover anymore.

Comment: @DanielSchepler No, the Sorgenfey line is the classical example that Lindelöfness is **not** preserved by products of two spaces (also the Michael line times the irrationals etc.) It **is** Lindelöf. Your argument does show correctly that $\mathbb{S}^2$ is not Lindelöf.

Comment: There is a classical theorem that for generalised ordered spaces (the Sorgenfrey line $\mathbb{S}$ is one)being ccc (there are no uncountable families of pairwise disjoint non-empty open sets) is equivalent to being hereditarily Lindelöf (all subspaces are Lindelöf). This equivalence even holds for all monotonically normal spaces. As $\mathbb{S}$ is separable it is ccc. Bit of overkill..

Comment: OK, I sort of thought I might be remembering things wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the $(a_\alpha, b_\alpha)$ need not cover $\mathbb{R}$ at all. That's too easy.
But it does not matter because we consider $$U = \bigcup_\alpha (a_\alpha,b_\alpha)$$ which is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ in the Euclidean topology (so it's second countable as all subspaces of the reals are, so $U$ is Lindelöf), and the $(a_\alpha, b_\alpha)$ are by definition an open cover of $U$.

So we can find a countable set of indices (corresponding to a countable subcover) $\{\alpha_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ such that
$$\bigcup_n (a_{\alpha_n}, b_{\alpha_n}) = \bigcup_\alpha (a_\alpha, b_\alpha)= U$$

So what elements $x$ do we potentially miss from the union of the subcover $$\mathcal{U} = \{[a_{\alpha_n}, b_{\alpha_n}): n \in \mathbb{N}\}\text{?}$$

So consider $$P=\mathbb{R}\setminus \cup\mathcal{U}$$

We will show this set is at most countable: 
Any $x \in P$ must be a point of the form $x=a_\alpha$ (or it would be in some $(a_\alpha,b_\alpha)$, as it must be covered, so then $x \in U \subseteq \cup\mathcal{U}$, contradiction), and we can pick a rational number $q_x \in (a_\alpha, b_\alpha)$ for that $\alpha$ (the rationals are dense so this can be done). Note that always $(x, q_x) \subseteq U$.

Suppose $x < y$ are two distinct points of $P$. 
Then I claim that $q_y \le q_x$ is not possible: suppose it is, then
we have that $x < y < q_y \le q_x$ and this implies that $y \in (x,q_x) \subseteq U$, which is impossible (again because then $y \notin P$).

So $q_x < q_y$ whenever $x < y$ are both in $P$. So the map $x \to q_x$ from $P$ into $\mathbb{Q}$ is injective and $P$ is indeed at most countable.

Now for each $x \in P$ add an $[a_{\alpha(x)}, b_{\alpha(x)})$ to cover it and note that

$$ \mathcal{U} \cup \{[a_{\alpha(x)}, b_{\alpha(x)}): x \in P\}$$

is a countable subcover of the original cover.

Comment: An alternative way: starting the same way, suppose $P$ is uncountable. Then it has a total point of condensation, in the usual reals-topology (from having a countable base). From this you can deduce a contradiction. And then the final bit is the same again.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be an open cover of the Sorgenfrey line (a.k.a. the right-half open topology, a.k.a. the lower-limit topology).

(I). For $x\in \mathbb R$ let $y\in V(x)$ iff $[\;y\geq x$ and $[x,y)$ can be covered by a countable subset of $C\;].$

We show by contradiction that $V(x)=[x,\infty):$

If $\;\inf (\;[x,\infty)$ \  $V(x)\;)=z\in \mathbb R $ then $[x,z)\subset V(x),$ so  for each $n\in \mathbb N$ let $C_n$ be a countable subset of $C$ that covers $[x, z-2^{-n}(z-x)).$ Then $\cup_{n\in \mathbb N}C_n$ is a countable subset of $C$ that covers $[x,z).$

But there exists $\sigma \in C$ and $r>0$ such that $[z,z+r)\subset \sigma,$ so $\{\sigma\}\cup (\cup_{n\in \mathbb N}C_n)$ is a countable subset of $C$ that covers $[x, z+r),$ implying $\inf (\;(x,\infty)$ \ $V(x)\;)\geq z+r>z,$ contrary to the def'n of $z.$

(II). So for each $n\in \mathbb Z$ let $D_n$ be a countable subset of $C$ that covers $[n,n+1)$ and let $D=\cup_{n\in \mathbb Z}D_n.$